# Login Activity gets Crashed after Splashing Activity

Tags: android, android-developer-api

I am working on an android project in which there are Login, Register, Main Activity and also a Splash Activity.
So in that, except Splash Activity, all activity gets crashed.
First Splash Activity gets executed then Main Activity gets Crashed.

> Here is the Splash Activity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try
                {
                    sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    Intent mainintent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(mainintent);
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

}
```

> Here is the Manifest.xml file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name="com.example.connect2every1.MainActivity">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.connect2every1.SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Login Activity, Register Activity, Main Activity, must be get executed
the main motive is that
after Splash Activity Login Activity must be executed.

Comment: Add the crush log from the logcat

Comment: you generally don't need splash screen. also you could use a handler instead of a thread.

Comment: Even if I don't use Splash Activity then also it gets Crashed

Comment: Why do you even need a timer for splash screen? just put the start activity code in onResume() without timer. And remove finish() call from onPause()

Comment: Even if I don't use Splash Activity then also it gets Crashed. If I directly execute a Login Activity as my first Activity then also its gets crashed and not only Login Activity but also Main , Register Activity.

Comment: @Bhagesh then you must put code of MainActivy because you put the code in SO that crashes. and also copy paste your crash log here. On a side note, since you have already posted your splash here, you can optimise it by temoving timer, starting activity in on resume, call finish after starting and remove finish from pause

Comment: If your MainActivity is crashing, could you include the code for the same. Also posting the stack trace might help.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the following code

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

           Intent mainintent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainintent);finish()


        }
    }, 2000);
```

After that remove finish() from onResume()

Comment: Using timer is bad practice for Splash screen. If you are not doing any processing or validations in Splash, then you must simply call starts activity in onResume. And most importantly finish must be called after start

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but he didn't need this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change UI from worker thread, only Main thread can change UI, so use `runOnUiThread` when starting activity.

```
Thread splash=new Thread(){
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                wait(2000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};
splash.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you **register your every Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`**?

If you did, **you won't be able to switch UI from a non-UI thread without a `Handler`**.

So in order to get your code work, you'll need to initialize a `Handler` in UI thread and post a `Runnable` instance with or without delay in UI or non-UI thread.

Here is the Code

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private mHander Handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        mHander = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(){
        mHander.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        },5000);
    }
}
```

and also remove `finish();` from `onPause()` method, because your current activity automatically gets closed when Runnable executes.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

First change your Activity name MainActivity to LoginActivity from Manifest file.

```
<activity android:name="com.example.connect2every1.LoginActivity ">

    </activity>
```

instead of

```
<activity android:name="com.example.connect2every1.MainActivity">

    </activity>
```

than, Use handler Class for splash screen

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        },4000);
```

Comment: If you change activity in manifest, you have to rename it in the java file and also you have to change its reference in other files, so what is the need to change the name?